# Allow space in textbox

Tags: javascript

So I have this code that should only allow letters to be typed in a textbox, but it's also not allowing to type space and I need it:

**JS :**

```
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        }
        else { return true; }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

**Question :** What should I do to allow spaces ?

Comment: try `if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 32)`. Space charCode is 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space char code is 32.

So, you should add an OR operator and check for `charCode == 32`

Like this snippet:

```
if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 32) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```